# Streaming several (YUV) videos using OpenGL

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, video-streaming

I'm trying to do high-throughput video streaming using OpenGL.  I thought I'd figured it all out with my genius programming architecture, but - surprise - when doing more serious tests, I've been stonewalled with a performance problem.

The story goes like this:

1. It all starts by reserving a stack of PBO's (say, a hundred+ or so):

   ```
   glGenBuffers(1, &index);
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, index);
   glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // reserve n_payload bytes to index/handle pbo_id

   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0); // unbind (not mandatory)
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, index); // rebind (not mandatory)

   payload = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

   glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER); // release pointer to mapping buffer ** MANDATORY **
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0); // unbind ** MANDATORY **
   ```

   YUV pixel data is copied into PBOs by separate decoder/uploader threads that use a common stack of available PBOs.  The "payload" pointers you see above, are accessed from these threads and data is copied (with memcpy) "directly" to the gpu. Once a PBO is used, it is returned to the stack.
2. I also pre-reserve textures for each separate video stream.  I reserve three textures (y, u and v), like this:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glGenTextures(1, &index);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, index);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, w, h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); // no upload, just reserve 
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // unbind
   ```

   Rendering is done in a "master thread" (remember, the decoder / uploader threads are separate beasts) that reads frames from a fifo queue.
3. A critical step in rendering is to copy data from PBOs to textures (tex->format is GL_RED):

   ```
   // y
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo->y_index);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->y_index); // this is the texture we will manipulate
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, tex->w, tex->h, tex->format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); // copy from pbo to texture 

   // u
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo->u_index);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->u_index); // this is the texture we will manipulate
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, tex->w/2, tex->h/2, tex->format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); // copy from pbo to texture 

   // v
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo->v_index);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->v_index); // this is the texture we will manipulate
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, tex->w/2, tex->h/2, tex->format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); // copy from pbo to texture 

   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0); // unbind // important!
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // unbind
   ```

And finally, the image is drawn using the OpenGL shading language (which is another story).

**The Question : Do you see any OpenGL performance bottlenecks here?**

Step (3) seems like a bottleneck, as it starts to consume too much time (up to 10+ milliseconds)!, when I'm trying to do this with several cameras.

Of course, this could be due to something else clogging the OpenGL pipeline - but everything else (glDrawElements, etc.) seems to take max. 1 millisecond.

I've been reading about problems people are having with glTexSubImage2D, but in my case, I'm simply filling the textures from PBOs.  This should be lightning fast - right?  Could the GL_RED format pose a problem by being non-optimal for the driver?

Another thing: I'm not doing de/reallocating here (I am using the same stack of pre-reserved PBO's), but re-allocating seems to be fast as well.. if I understood correctly this one .. ?

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming

Any insight highly appreciated..!

P. S. The complete project is here: https://github.com/elsampsa/valkka-core

**EDIT 1:**

I did some profiling:  Every now and then during the streaming, both the PBO=>texture loading (as shown in the code snippet) and glXMakeCurrent go completely crazy and they both consume 10+ milliseconds (!)  This happens quite sporadically.  I tried to add some glFinish calls after each PBO=>texture load, but with little success (it seemed to stabilize things a bit .. but actually I'm not sure)

**EDIT 2:**

I am slowly getting there .. Ran some tests where I (a) upload with PBO to GPU and then (b) copy from PBO to texture (like in that sample code).  The speed seems to depend on the texture format in "glTexImage2D".  I try to match the texture's format and OpenGL internal format, by setting them to GL_RED and GL_RED (or GL_R8), respectively.   But that is slow.  Instead, if I use GL_RGBA for both, PBO=>TEX is lightning fast.. 100x faster !

Here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

it says that

> GL_RED : Each element is a single red component. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha. Each component is clamped to the range [0,1].

.. but I don't want OpenGL to do that!  How can I tell it that it's just plain LUMA, i.e. one-byte-per-pixel and no need to convert/fill it, cause I will just use it in the shader program.

Maybe this is impossible and I should use buffer textures instead (as suggested in the comments) .. ?  Buffer textures don't try to convert anything.. they just handle it as raw payload, right?

**EDIT 3:**

I'm trying to get dma to the texture buffer object:

```
// let's reserve a TBO
glGenBuffers(1, &tbo_index); // a buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo_index); // .. what is it
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // .. how much
std::cout << "tbo " << tbo_index << std::endl;
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0); // unbind

// generate a texture
glGenTextures(1, &tex_index);
std::cout << "texture " << tex_index << std::endl;

// let's try to get dma to the texture buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo_index); // bind
payload = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY); // ** TODO: doesn't work
glUnmapBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER); // release pointer to mapping buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0); // unbind

std::cout << "tbo " << tbo_index << " at " << (long unsigned int)payload << std::endl;
```

Doesn't work.. payload is always a null pointer.  glMapBuffer works ok with PBOs though.  It should work with TBO's as well.

Comment: **glTexSubImage2D** can be a bottleneck, especially if you try to use it in parallel from different threads. Note that you can reduce the overhead significantly if you pass Y, U and V data in a single chunk (the shader must be wiser to handle this YUV buffer).

Comment: There is only one thread doing the OpenGL calls (the decoder/uploader threads just use memcpy)

Comment: I would avoid the PBOs and textures. Map a buffer as a GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER. Then you can fetch directly in the shader. See [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. please check out the edits Alex Cohn and Ripi2 - I need help with this!  :(

Comment: A small test program here : https://github.com/elsampsa/opengl-texture-streaming

Comment: Search SO for `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` There's a lot of helpful q&a. Also, you need `glTexBuffer` see  [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture) linked to your `tbo_index` buffer.